# Java Persistence Find Case Sensitive Data Retriving

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence

I'm using `javax.persistence.EntityManager` in a programme. So I've a user table which use `String` `username` as the `primary key` in a mysql database. So when i find a value from a username i found a problem.

Sample Data :

> username : MobileUser001 username : MobileUser002

I used `public <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey);`

So when i send "mobileuser001" , "MobileUser001" , "mobileUser001" as the primary key Persistence searched the correct data. But it gives the username what we input, Not the username with correct case in the database.

**I need the correct case "MobileUser001" for any input like i mentioned above.**

Comment: can you try `@Column(name = "userName", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(250) COLLATE latin1_general_cs")` on userName ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ same result

Comment: Can you post code where you are passing user name. ?

Comment: User user = userDao.read(username);

public T read(PK id) {
  
    return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
  }

Comment: public T read(PK id) {
  
    return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
  }

Comment: User user = userDao.read(username);

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609087/database-independent-string-comparison-with-jpa  it have answer, COLLATE at DB level then try which I have provided at JPA level.